# Whenever I try to build a new ionic project angular from console it give me, npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
i updated npm to latest version, i tried to force clear the cache didn't resolve.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is npm modules are unable to download from node repository central, i suggest you to follow below steps....

1)Run Command npm config edit
2)then proxy file opens in notepad
3)try to add registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/ and save
4)make sure to add strict-ssl=false in case above doesnt work...
Thanks !!!!!

Comment: in my case registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/ is added and I turned to false, unfourtunately the same problem has occured.... is there another way?

Comment: i tried also Yarn install also gave me a weird error....

[1/4] Resolving packages...
⠈ @babel/helper-plugin-utils@^7.14.5node:_tls_wrap:411
        owner._tlsOptions.isServer ? 'server' : 'client', err,

Comment: can you paste the console logs here

Comment: Hello, i already got rid of this problem. I also faced another one and corrected. Why these problems are showing? At first I didnt get any of these errors

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded the node version to 14.0.0 using nvm version, if anyone having same problem, this was my solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you search SO for `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')` then you currently get four results, all in the last month. So it looks like me like a genuine new bug. What fixed it for me was installing git on my system (possibly unrelated) and switching to Yarn.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this was an issue in node 17.x. I reverted back to 16.13 which is the latest LTS release at time of writing and my Azure DevOps pipeline started working again.